# googletest integrated in CLR/CLI Compilation error LNK2028

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++-cli, googletest

Im totally new to google testing in CLI. Just managed to set up and integrate google test with visual studio 2012. However, when I try to include the header file of my project with my tester.h file (because I want to test the functions in that headerfile), I encountered the following error:

```
Error   2   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0006FB) "public: __thiscall ExpenseTracker::ExpenseTracker(void)" (??0ExpenseTracker@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "private: virtual void __thiscall enter_settings_user_login_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@enter_settings_user_login_Test@@$$FEAEXXZ)  C:\Users\Jacky\Desktop\EzXpns3\test_project\main.obj    test_project
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall ExpenseTracker::ExpenseTracker(void)" (??0ExpenseTracker@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "private: virtual void __thiscall enter_settings_user_login_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@enter_settings_user_login_Test@@$$FEAEXXZ)   C:\Users\Jia Wei\Desktop\EzXpns3\test_project\main.obj  test_project
```

I have tried including dependencies gtestd.lib, kernel32.lib, user32.lib, advapi32.lib, Ws2_32.lib

Problem slightly resolved. Instead of having expenseTracker.h and ExpenseTracker.cpp, I placed all my implementation of ExpenseTracker.h in the header file itself and everything compiled nicely and test run. However, my entire project has been built on both header file and cpp file and its not very wise to redo everything for testing purposes right? Could anyone help with this?

Attached below are my header files.

//tester.h

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h" //include to use Google Unit test's stuff
#include "C:\Users\Jacky\Desktop\EzXpns3\Source - testing\EzXpns2\ExpenseTracker.h"

using namespace std;

class ExpenseTracker;
/************************************************************************/

/* We write test cases here */

/************************************************************************/

TEST(basic_test, add_simple_route)
{
    ASSERT_EQ(1, 1);
}

TEST(enter_settings, user_login)
{
    ExpenseTracker :: ExpenseTracker();
    //loadUserInfo();
    string username = "XXX_XXX";
    string password = "12345";
    //myTracker -> loadUserInfo();
    //bool result = myTracker -> login(username, password);
    //ASSERT_EQ(true, result);
}

void runTest(int argument_count, char** argument_vars)
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argument_count, argument_vars); //initialize GTest
    RUN_ALL_TESTS();
    std::getchar(); //pause the program after all the testing
}
```

//main.cpp

```
#include "tester.h"
#include <cstdio>


using namespace System;
using namespace testing;

int main(int argument_count, char** argument_vars)
{
    //int argc;
    //char** argv;
    //runTest(argc, argv);
    //InitGoogleTest(argc, argv);   

    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argument_count, argument_vars); //initialize GTest
    RUN_ALL_TESTS();
    std::getchar();


    return 0;
}
```

//ExpenseTracker.h, the file which I want to include

```
#ifndef _EXPENSETRACKER_H
#define _EXPENSETRACKER_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "user2.h"

using namespace std;

class ExpenseTracker
{
private:
    vector<User*> allMyUsers;

public:
    ExpenseTracker(); //empty constructor
    void addUser(User*);
    int findUser(string);
    bool login(string, string);
    void loadUserInfo();
    User* getUser(string);
    int getUserSize();
};

#endif;
```

Comment: You've declared a constructor but haven't defined it. I guess what you really wanted was `ExpenseTracker() {}; // empty constructor`. I'll also point out that it's common practice to place tests / test fixtures in a cpp/cc file rather than in a header file.

Comment: Hi Michael, to be honest Im not exactly sure what Im doing, probably trial and error and hoping that I can bump into the correct answer. Im trying to test whether my "login" method works. Before I can test this, I actually have to call the method "loadUserInfo". Could you guide me a little on the syntax? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide an implementation for the constructor. In other words, you should change:

```
 ExpenseTracker(); //empty constructor
```

into:

```
ExpenseTracker() {} // empty constructor
```

However, since the constructor is empty you might as well remove it entirely!